# Is it possible to cout object in C++ like this obj << cout << endl

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

We had a class where professor asked us to overload `ostream` to print object this way (*saying we have object t*)

```
cout << t << endl;
```

Then we were asked to cout the same object this way

```
t << cout << endl;
```

How does this work and why?

```cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, T& t)
{
   return o << t.member;
}

// This is usual way and "normal" that I know about but won't work on both ways
```

Expected output is the same, but second way is confusing. Why would anyone want to use it?

Comment: It's unclear to me which of these questions you want an answer to.

Comment: The professor isn't saying, "You should always write `t << cout << endl`", but the professor is instead testing your understanding of operators and operator overloading.

Comment: `ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, T& t)` should be `ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const T& t)`

Answer (score 4):

As any [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) or tutorial should tell you, for any operator `X` the expression `a X b` will (if a suitable overload is found) be equal to `operatorX(a, b)`.

Or if `a` (in `a X b`) have overloaded the operator as a member function, then it's equal to `a.operatorX(b)`.

If we now take `cout << t`, that will call either `operator<<(cout, t)` or `cout.operator<<(t)` depending on the type of `t`.

As should be easy to guess, reversing the order to `t << cout` would then be `operator<<(t, cout)` or `t.operator<<(cout)`.